# Is it possible to add a Facebook comment via an API for a specific page to avoid the need for the comment plugin?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

Suppose I have a page, http://foo.com/bar.  Is it possible to use the Graph API to let a use add a comment for that url to avoid the need to host the Facebook comment plugin?

I have a case where I want to let user sign in with Facebook but create my own comment UI.  I know I can read all the comments with a call like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=http://imdb.com

(assuming the link I care about is `http://imdb.com`).

However, I can't find a documented way to allow me to write a comment for a user given a specific access_token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Previously there was a loophole to `POST` to the `/comments` endpoint with a `messages` parameter, but this is now closed. You *must* use the comments plugin to add comments.